# Add two objects in the same list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects. Each object contains an ID and a value. There are several objects which have the same ID but different values. How would I go about adding the values together based on the matching ID? Additionally, how would I go about removing one entry after the addition is complete?

The object in question:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Below is where I am getting the duplicate objects from a list of all objects. I'm simply getting all the duplicate IDs into a list of strings and then grabbing the entire duplicate object in the duplicateObjects list.

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = GetMyObjectsList();
List<string> duplicateIds = myObjects.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                                                .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                                                .Select(group => group.Key).ToList();

List<MyObject> duplicateObjects = myObjects.Where(x => duplicateIds.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

I'm stuck on the last steps which are adding the duplicate values and then removing one of the duplicates. How would I accomplish this with Linq?

Comment: For clarification - So you want to "sum" all the values grouped by ID and then you remove one of the duplicates ? On what basis would the duplicate to be removed would be chosen (last item in the group ). ?

Comment: Yes, I want to sum based on ID and then remove one of the duplicates. There is no basis on which duplicate to remove as they would be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the list look like this

```
    var list  =  new MyObject[]
    {
        new MyObject {ID = 1, Value = 2},
        new MyObject {ID = 2, Value = 2},
        new MyObject {ID = 1, Value = 3},
        new MyObject {ID = 4, Value = 4},
        new MyObject {ID = 2, Value = 4},
    };
```

Then just select from list group by ID and sum value like this

```
var result  = (from tm in list
                   group  tm by tm.ID into Test 
                   select  new 
                   {
                       ID =  Test.Key,
                       Value  =  Test.Sum(x => x.Value)
                   });
```

Output

```
ID = 1,  Value = 5
ID = 2,  Value = 6
ID = 4,  Value = 4
```

working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/REELfL)

Comment: That's almost working. How would I get an additional field in result object? Say the original object has a Name, the following gives me an error:

var result  = (from tm in list
                   group  tm by tm.ID into Test 
                   select  new 
                   {
                       ID =  Test.Key,
                       Value  =  Test.Sum(x => x.Value),
                       Name = Test.Name,
                   });

Comment: @Rhendar just do like this ` Name = Test.Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault(),`

Comment: I just did that and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question correctly.As clarified in the comment,you want to "sum" all the values grouped by ID and then remove one of the duplicates. Please verify if the following is how you could like it to be behave.

```
var duplicates = myObjects.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                          .Select(group => new { Group = group.Count() > 1 ? group.ToList().Take(group.Count()-1) : group.ToList(),Sum=group.Count()});
```

For Input

[image]

Output

[image]

If you need to exclude non-duplicates, then you would need to include an additional Where Condition

```
var duplicates = myObjects.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
                          .Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
                          .Select(group => new { Group = group.Count() > 1 ? group.ToList().Take(group.Count()-1) : group.ToList(),Sum=group.Count()});
```